# How can I install the Photos demo from the Ocean WP theme?

Tags: plugins, themes

I'm working with a new install of WordPress on DreamHost. I'm using DreamHost's automated WordPress installation feature for a non-managed site (i.e., not DreamPress). After that I'm attempting to work with the Photo demo from the Ocean WP theme. Here's what I've done.

1. After installing WordPress using the Install WordPress button under the domain's "Manage" section (keeping all recommended plugins), I followed the instructions in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BSx26ucgeo) video.
2. First clicked Appearance>Themes and clicked "Add New Theme," found the Ocean WP theme and clicked "Install." Once it was installed I clicked "Activate."
3. This brought up a notification in the browser that I should install the Ocean Extra plugin. The video shows it differently (it's slightly obsolete), but the effect was the same, so I clicked "Install & Activate Ocean Extra." When that was finished I clicked "Allow & Continue" to opt into security and feature updates, etc.
4. The video then directs the user to the "Theme Panel" in the main menu, but [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twUc0rHnBo0&t=65s) shows that it's since been relocated to the main menu's OceanWP section, so I clicked that, then clicked "Install Demos."
5. The demo I'm interested in is Photos, so I click "Import" for that theme. A dialog informed me of a few prerequisites, the only one of which I didn't have was "Ocean Social Sharing," so I installed and activated that plugin in the dialog and clicked "Go to the next step."
6. I left all the checkboxes about the available imports (XML, customizer settings, etc.) checked and clicked "Install this demo."
7. After a few minutes with the install process dialog, it reported that the demo has successfully imported and offered a link to "See the result," which I clicked.
8. A new tab opened, and this is the result:

[image]

It seems the HTML came over but no CSS and only one of the images? Note that the live preview looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it? Note that this is a brand new site, so if I have to start over from the absolute beginning, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the "Ocean" support. That's where this question belongs.